# Bash db function into python script

Tags: python, mysql, bash, shell

I have a problem that, in the bash profile, I was doing select 2 columns from a table and filtering all data which the framework column value is java into testcases file.   But I want to use that python,  I tried a lot of ways but without any success.

```
echo "select class, testcase from test_cases where framework = 'Java';" | mysql -h vm.dev.midasplayer.com --ssl-mode=DISABLED -u ${DB_USER} -p${DB_PASSWORD} tabletest > testcases
```

I try using the following python to connect the DB but then how to perform the SQL query and then import it into a file?  Any help here will be much appreciated

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="vm.dev.midasplayer.com",
  user="username",
  password="password"
)

print(mydb)
```

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title. There is not _bash function_ in use anywhere in your code. Your question seems to be solely on how to execute a MySql query in Python, and how to store text into a file using Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the most basic and elementary for backend developers who start to use a relational database. You wil find a lot if information in the internet with these google searches:

- simple mysql crud with [java, python, c#, nodejs, etc]
- simple mysql select with [java, python, c#, nodejs, etc]

Also you can add at the end of google search the following commands to get pdfs or ppts used in thousands of courses of all the world :)

- simple mysql select with python **filetype:ppt**
- simple mysql select with python **filetype:pdf**

### Learning mode

If you have time to learn steps by step I recommend to read carefully all the information found with the recommended searches in the previous section

I share here some useful pdfs

- https://www.google.com/search?q=python+mysql+filetype:pdf&client=ubuntu&hs=1SN&channel=fs&sxsrf=AJOqlzUQ95ilbcWWZpmZXoNsQND7eLMl8g:1674408020105&ei=VHDNY86RBuXH5OUPkfaV0AY&start=30&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjOi_3519v8AhXlI7kGHRF7BWo4FBDw0wN6BAgFEBc&biw=1149&bih=683&dpr=1
- https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-python-en.a4.pdf
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_mysql/python_mysql_tutorial.pdf
- https://no2imphal.kvs.ac.in/sites/default/files/Chapter%2010%20-%20Interface%20Python%20with%20MySQL.pdf
- https://isip.piconepress.com/courses/temple/ece_3822/resources/tutorials/python/python_database_access.pdf
- http://python.mykvs.in/uploads/tutorials/XIIComp.Sc.34.pdf
- [https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/teaching/ap/examples/scripts_python_dbapi.pdf](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ehgs/teaching/ap/examples/scripts_python_dbapi.pdf)
- https://ictswami.files.wordpress.com/2019/10/python-mysql-database.pdf
- https://labdeck.com/examples/python/py-db3/table-create-mysql-python.pdf
- https://pdfsecret.com/download/a-step-by-step-guide-to-using-mysql-with-python-this-tutorial-will-help-you-set-up-a-mysql-connection-from-a-python-program-we-assume-you-al-_59fa6f74d64ab28ae25e009a_pdf
- https://www.ijsr.net/archive/v8i2/ART20194929.pdf
- https://theswissbay.ch/pdf/Gentoomen%20Library/Programming/Python/MySQL%20for%20Python%20%282010%29.pdf

If links in the future are offline, check this https://github.com/open-source-education/junior-software-developer/tree/main/jsd-306

### If you don't have time to learn

**Not recommended** but if you don't have time to learn, you could use https://gist.github.com to search a code ready to use

- https://gist.github.com/search?q=mysql+select+python&ref=searchresults

**pre-requisites**

```
pip install mysql-connector
pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

**code**

```py
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import errorcode

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='devopsschool1',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='MyNewPass')

    sql_select_Query = "select * from Laptop"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    print("Total number of rows in Laptop is: ", cursor.rowcount)

    print("\nPrinting each laptop record")
    for row in records:
        print("Id = ", row[0], )
        print("Name = ", row[1])
        print("Price  = ", row[2])
        print("Purchase date  = ", row[3], "\n")

except Error as e:
    print("Error reading data from MySQL table", e)
finally:
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        connection.close()
        cursor.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Snippet source: https://gist.github.com/devops-school/eab2f34e05145b9227ba413b1aa42da7#file-read-py